# Вынос нескольких папок на отдельный диск в Linux

Tags: linux

Устанавливаю Arch Linux.2 диска - SSD и HDD

Подскажите, возможно ли вынести /var и /home на отдельный диск не создавая 2 раздела.т.е. чтобы /home хранился в /dev/sdb2 в папке home, а /var в /dev/sdb2 в папке var.При этом система была в /dev/sda1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мож я чо не понимаю? Но мне казалось, что не папка на разделе, а раздел монтируется в папку...

Что мешает при установке на SSD-вениеке создать раздел (не забыть про swap, хотя....) и монтировать его в "/" (корень), а на другом венике создать два раздела и монтировать один из них в "/home" а другой в "/var"?

---

Критика. Arch - не самый дружественный (юзерфрендли) дистрибутив... Я бы рекомендовал начать с Ubuntu и, в первую очередь, [теории](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_linux) по Вашему вопросу.

Comment: Мне помогли слова раздел монтируется в папку. Это означает, что то, что я хотел - не имеет смысла. Тут дело было не в Арче - а в теории по вопросу и моих знаниях. Арч мне подходит - поэтому менять его нет смысла. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Всегда велкам)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю все реализовать по-человечьи...Ставь систему, можно со стандартными настройками, дальше грузимся в нее и ждем вывода sudo blkid...

Выясняешь UUIDы интересующих тебя дисков\разделов, создаешь нужные и идешь в /etc/fstab, там пишешь соответственно нужные тебе UUIDы и запиливаешь в нужные каталоги, предварительно их создав. Пример:

```
# blkid/dev/sda3: UUID="5f3af549-a442-421f-9158-b4fc2a462f80" TYPE="ext3"/dev/sdb1: UUID="a19c8500-f5d4-48f6-a950-817069850ea6" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"/dev/sda1: UUID="df73f81e-6364-420b-a700-153ce7366508" TYPE="ext4"/dev/sda2: UUID="ba57734c-32fe-4523-bfbd-7805f1e87601" TYPE="swap"
```

nano/etc/fstab

UUID=5f3af549-a442-421f-9158-b4fc2a462f80 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1

UUID=df73f81e-6364-420b-a700-153ce7366508 /public                 ext4    defaults        1 2

UUID=a19c8500-f5d4-48f6-a950-817069850ea6 /home/db           ext3    defaults        1 2

В примере корневой раздел по-дефолту, остальные раскиданы на другие винты (уже после установки)

Comment: Я понимаю, если сервак крутится благополучно пару лет и тут ему дисковое пространство подвалило...Но геморроиться так при УСТАНОВКЕ системы, да еще начинающему... Нет уж, увольте!---UPСам начинающий)))

Comment: То, что тут написано мне в принципе понятно. При установке буду редактировать fstab. Только заместо UUID сразу использую имена дейвайсов.

Comment: Сори, @Octogen, совсем вылетело, что Arch...

Comment: Крайне не рекомендую использовать имена дисков вместо UUID, бывают случаи смены имени девайса при подключении другого диска или флэхи. UUID - это то, что бабушка прописала, он всегда неизменен!!! Делайте правильно и не будет проблем никогда.

Comment: @Octogen как на счет лейблов? там можно вразумительно их обозвать и тоже доступно через blkid.  можно и lvm накинуть

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать и на одном разделе /var и /home, используя **символические ссылки**. Сам такие штуки делал, когда /home распух в несколько раз. Для этого нужно создать один раздел и замонтировать его, например в /mnt/big_volume.  Затем нужно скопировать содержимое нужных каталогов в /mnt/big_volume. Очень удобно использовать для этого Midnight Commander, так как он сохраняет все права и атрибуты файлов по умолчанию(в cp можно забыть прописать нужные опции и угробить чего-нибудь, если переносишь часть системы).

Копирование с помощью утилиты cp будет примерно таким:

```
cp -rv --preserve=all /home /mnt/big_storagecp -rv --preserve=all /var /mnt/big_storage
```

Затем удаляем /home и /var.

```
rm -rvf /home /var
```

а лучше не удалять, а переименовать, так безопаснее:

```
mv /home /home.oldmv /var /var.old
```

затем создаём символические ссылки:

```
ln -s /mnt/big_volume/home /ln -s /mnt/big_volume/var /
```

Бинго!

P.S. Если всё работает и ничего не потерялось, через некоторое время можно удалить резервные копии /home.old  и /var.old

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно... :) При разметки диска будут доступны все диски... Создашь раздел /home на любом диске в независимости где корень...

Comment: А как их подцепить то?    mount /dev/sda1 /mnt # это кореньТеперь имеем раздел /dev/sdb2 . Как прописать, что папки home и var должны размещаться там?    mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/home # прописывает только 1 папку

Comment: mount /dev/sdb2/home /mnt/home

Comment: Пишет: special device /dev/sdb2/home does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)/dev/sdb2 - это устройство. а home папка наверное поэтому не получается.

Comment: Давай разберёмся... У тебя уже есть установленная система и ты хочешь примонтировать каталог home на отдельном диске? Если да то это надо прописывать в fstab...

Comment: Нет. Я ставлю с 0. На данный момент есть только /dev/sda1 - ext4/dev/sdb1 - swap/dev/sdb2 - ext4Система не установлена. Дальше или создать ещё 1 раздел для /var, что как-то не очень нравится. Либо каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы /var и /home размещались на /dev/sdb2

Comment: Вот тут показано как создавать и монтировать разделы при установке... http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/12242/